# FragmentResultListener is not invoked after returning to fragment from another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a problem with setFragmentResultListener callback in my project. You can imagine that there is an activity with a fragment A on this. In fragment A, I set up a FragmentResultListener like this

```
setFragmentResultListener(AddImageDialogFragment::class.java.simpleName, this) { _, bundle -> }
```

and a button that clicking on it will open AddImageDialogFragment. This is code to open the dialog

```
AddImageDialogFragment.newInstance().show(parentFragmentManager, null)
```

In the dialog, I used this code to set result to Fragment A

```
setFragmentResult(this::class.java.simpleName, bundleOf())
```

*The problem is that you can see in 2 case below*

**Case 1 (worked well)**

1. Add fragment B to the activity that has already fragment A
2. Pop backstack to fragment A
3. Add open AddImageDialogFragment from fragment A and call
   setFragmentResult -> the FragmentResultListener still worked well

**Case 2 (not working)**

1. Add fragment B to the activity that has already fragment A
2. Add fragment C to the activity that has already fragment A and B
3. Pop backstack to fragment C -> B -> A
4. Add open AddImageDialogFragment from fragment A and call
   setFragmentResult -> **the FragmentResultListener was not called**

Does anyone know what happened to my code? I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I have realized that the problem is that the fragmentManager does not match with each fragment context and it causes some mess in my code. For launching a fragment inside fragment, it would be childFragmentManager instead of parentFragmentManager